# install hibernate tools in eclipse helios

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

i want to install hibernate in eclipse helios via http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/helios/
during the installation of software i have this error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.hibernate.eclipse.console,3.4.1.v20111025-0625-H210-Final.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: fea0d20b63dde5eea8ac9441a7ffbd8d and found 22313e1a2eb7899f86b378b058007522.
Unable to read repository at http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/JBossTools-3.2.2.Final/plugins/org.hibernate.eclipse.mapper_3.4.1.v20111025-0625-H210-Final.jar.
Read timed out
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing all that? Helios has a built-in plugin installer.

The url you gave says it all right at the top:

> To install JBoss Tools, start up Eclipse (3.6.2 or above) then:
>   Help > Install New Software... >
>   and add this URL:
>   http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/helios/

That's all there is to it. I suggest you try this, and *don't* copy any files yourself.

Comment: If you have already done what you said in the question you've probably corrupted your entire Eclipse installation, so completely delete and reinstall helios then try installing this plugin again. Eclipse is easily corrupted if you start messing with its files.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Eclipse Helios, you could install JBoss tools (in which the Hibernate tools are included) through the "Marketplace" as well. As far as I can remember, I installed Hibernate tools on both Eclipse Helios and Indigo this way, and it went just fine.